# Usar header("Location ./") sem perder o conteúdo do formulário

Tags: php

Estou trabalhando com um formulário de metodo POST e caso o usuário envie-o com algum campo preenchido de maneira incorreta quero que ele volte para a página mas sem perder o conteúdo preenchido anteriormente.

Eu pretendia usar `header("Location ./")`, mas não sei se isso vai manter o que já havia sido preenchido. E utilizar método GET não é uma opção.

Comment: E onde é que está o código referente a sua pergunta?

Comment: Não é pra isso que o Location serve. Se quer persistir os dados, simplesmente processe-os no PHP que recebe o form. Use o Location apenas em caso de sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Uma abordagem é que a página na action do seu formulário, retorne o próprio formulário com a presença das informações de erro (quais campos devem ser modificados pelo usuário) e com os inputs preenchidos. Por exemplo, você tem um arquivo `form.php` e outro chamado `verifica.php`:

form.php

```
<!--Verifica se tem alguma mensagem de erro
(quando incluido pelo arquivo verifica.php (require_once))
-->
<?php
    //verifica se existe a variavel $mensagemErros
    //ela só vai existir se o arquivo form.php
    //for incluido pelo arquivo verifica.php
    if(isset($mensagemErros)){
        echo '<div>' . $mensagemErros . '</div>';
    }
?>

<!--No formulario basta checar o array $_POST para exibir 
alguma informação submetida anteriormente-->
<form method="post" action="verifica.php">
    <input type="text" name="a" 
    value="<?php echo isset($_POST['a']) ? $_POST['a'] : '';?>">
    <input type="text" name="b"
    value="<?php echo isset($_POST['a']) ? $_POST['b'] : '';?>">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar_form">
</form>
```

verifica.php

```
<?php

//verifica se o formulario foi enviado
if(isset($_POST['enviar_form'])){
    //verifica se tem erros (alguma função feita por você)
    $temErros = true;

    if($temErros){
        $mensagemErros = "Foram encontrados os seguintes erros: ...";
        require_once './form.php';  
        //ao chamar o arquivo form.php, o array global $_POST
        //estara disponivel, sendo possivel alterar o atributo
        //value de cada input, com os dados submetidos pelo usuario
    }else{
        //vai para outro lugar
        header('Location: index.php');  
    }
}

//nada mais deve ser impresso
//para não se "misturar" com o html do formulário
```

O usuário inicialmente acessa o arquivo `form.php`, quando o formulário for submetido, será chamada a página `verifica.php`, se houver algum erro de validação, o `verifica.php`, retornará o arquivo `form.php`, mostrando as informações de erro e os inputs com os valores anteriormente submetidos.

Comment: Mas não são mensagens de erros que o AP quer exibir, mas sim manter o formulário preenchido, para não ter que obrigar o usuário repreenchê-lo.

Comment: De certa forma engloba as duas coisas, pois assim o usuário poderá saber qual campo deve ser editado. Talvez eu não tenha deixado claro que são feitas as duas coisas: preenchimento do formulário com os dados anteriores e indicação de quais campos precisam ser alterados.

Comment: Ah, sim, havia lido errado. De fato ele irá preencher.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta, pois relendo agora, vi que dá a entender que só são exibidas mensagens de erro.